# How to make a long label inline with an input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align a long `label` with an `input` element. I have used `form-inline` which is working with short label but moving to next line with a long label text.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" /> 
    <label>The patient continues to demonstrate progress towards meeting the current set of treatment goals. As a result, the current treatment plan has been extended for another </label>
   <input  type="number" class="" name="" />
    <label>visits</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: set `width` for the input element

Comment: @Viira i have already tried with width

Comment: I've added my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set `display: inline` for the label, so that it will fit your content.

```css
.form-inline label {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" /> 
    <label>The patient continues to demonstrate progress towards meeting the current set of treatment goals. As a result, the current treatment plan has been extended for another </label>
   <input  type="number" class="" name="" />
    <label>visits</label>
 </div>
```

For some reasons this snippet is not working in here. See [here](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/vYZPNGv)